# Поддерживается ли директива 'report-to' CSP в Google Chrome?

Tags: http, google-chrome, webbrowser, xss, csp

Поддерживается ли директива 'report-to' CSP в Google Chrome? Складывается такое впечатление что CSP заброшенная технология, по крайне мере google.com её не использует и SO кстати тоже.

На MDN написано что вообще нигде не поддерживается:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-to

Comment: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5826576096690176

Comment: А почему не ответом? Надо отслеживать https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=676016 Спасибо.

Comment: Потому что понятия не имею что можно написать в 30 символов) Пусть ответ здесь полежит пока)

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что ещё не произошел переход от директивы [report-uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-uri) (сейчас браузерами поддерживается именно она).

При чтении MDN на тему CSP, может возникать некоторая путаница за счет того, что актуальная версия помечается как устаревшая, так как MDN, судя по всему, ориентируется на [третью](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/) версию стандарта (находящуюся в стадии черновика), в то время как в браузерах на данный момент реализована только поддержка [второй](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/).

*CSP не является устаревшей технологией. Наоборот, серьёзные проекты как раз стараются её внедрять (например, вы можете встретить CSP на gmail и других почтовых сервисах).*

*Разумеется, ещё далеко не все веб-ресурсы поддержали CSP: процесс внедрения во многих случаях осложняется огромным количеством легаси-кода, написанного без учета особенностей этой технологии.*